# Enum in Read from Database

Tags: c#, database, enums

I have a problem.
In my code I have an enum, that lists different sectors of industry. The value of the enum is read from a database.

When i try to cast the string from the database I get an `InvalidCastException`. I know that the problem is the enum, since all other values that are returned are strings. How can I fix this problem.

Here is the code:

```
public enum EnBranche
    {
        Metall = 1, 
        Informatik = 2, 
        Einzelhandel = 3, 
        Landwirtschaft = 4, 
        Energie = 5,  
        Gesundheitswirtschaft = 6, 
        Industrie = 7, 
        Tourismus = 8, 
        Logistik = 9
    };

var firma = FirmaFuellen(dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                                         dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(),
                                         dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString(),
                                         (int) dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[4],
                                         dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString(),
                                         **(EnBranche) dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[5]);**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
(EnBranche) Enum.Parse(typeof(EnBranche),
                       dataSet.Tables["Firmen"].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString())
```